# Show original referral with PayPal payment Buy Now button

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to get actual referral information in Google Analytics when using PayPal for payments using Classic GA tracking code. There are two options from my [test page](http://atomicvan.com/product.html):

- go to the Cart page and select PayPal from there - it works fine and with utm_nooverride=1 it shows the original referral
- use the PayPal Buy Now button without reaching the cart - it keeps showing PayPal as referral for the transaction.

Anyone has ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

**Maggieto**, how about using [referral exclusion](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/)?

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to make it work for the Classic GA. Even with Universal and added paypal.com in the exclusion list, I still see it as referral - of visits and transactions.